# Any two bases of a free module have the same cardinality.

Tags: ring-theory, set-theory, examples-counterexamples, free-modules

I am a graduate student of Mathematics.I am interested in modules.I have some queries about free modules. Let $R$ be a commutative (unital) ring and $M$ be a free $R$-module,then:

$1.$ Are the cardinalities of any two bases of $M$ same?(If not,give a counterexample)

$2.$ If the free module has a finite basis,then is it true?

I want to know these things because I want to differentiate between vector spaces and free modules.Can someone provide me with suitable proofs and counterexamples?I have tried but my list of examples is too limited to answer these questions.Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very late, but since both OP and myself are unfamiliar with tensor products, I’d like to provide a more detailed answer based on [@Aphelli](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/556825/aphelli)’s in case anyone else might find it useful.

**Constructing a vector space.**

Let $R\neq 0$ be a commutative ring (with $1$) and $M$ a free $R$-module with any basis $\mathbf{B}$. Let $I$ be a maximal ideal of $R$, then it is an easy exercise to show that $M/IM$ is an $R/I$-module (vector space, since $R/I$ is a field) where
$$\begin{aligned}
IM&=\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}i_km_k \mid n\in \mathbf{N}, i_k \in I, m_k\in M \right\}\\&= \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}i_kb_k \mid n\in \mathbf{N}, i_k \in I, b_k\in \mathbf{B} \right\}.
\end{aligned}$$
The scalar multiplication is given by
$$
R/I \times M/IM \rightarrow M/IM : (r+I,m+IM) \mapsto rm+IM,
$$
which is easily shown to be well-defined and a valid scalar multiplication noting that $rm$ is the scalar multiplication for $M$ as an $R$-module.

Now we’ll show that $\mathbf{B}’:=\{b+IM\mid b \in \mathbf{B}\}$ is a basis for $M/IM$ and that $|\mathbf{B}|=|\mathbf{B}’|$.

**Showing  $|\mathbf{B}|=|\mathbf{B}’|$.**

First we’ll show $|\mathbf{B}|=|\mathbf{B}’|$ by showing that $\psi:\mathbf{B}\rightarrow \mathbf{B}’ : b \mapsto b+IM$ is a bijection. It is clear that $\psi$ is surjective. Suppose $\psi(b_1)=\psi(b_2)$ for $b_1,b_2 \in \mathbf{B}$, then $b_1-b_2\in IM$ and if $b_1$ and $b_2$ are distinct, then by the uniqueness of the lineair combination $1\cdot b_1 + (-1)\cdot b_2$ in $IM \subseteq M$, we must have $1\in I$. This contradicts $I$ being maximal, so $b_1=b_2$ as required.

**Showing that $\mathbf{B}’$ is a basis.**

It is clear that $\mathbf{B’}$ is a spanning set for $M/IM$. Suppose that we have $r_k \in R$ and any finite subset $\varnothing \neq\{b_1+IM,\ldots,b_n+IM\}\subseteq \mathbf{B}’$ such that
$$
r_1b_1 + \ldots + r_nb_n \in IM.
$$
Since the $b_k+IM$ are distinct (per definition) and $\psi$ is bijective, the $b_k$ are also distinct. So again, by the uniqueness of the linear combination in $IM\subseteq M$ we must have  $r_k\in I$, so $r_k +I = 0 +I$.

**Conclusion.**

So $\mathbf{B}’$ is a basis for the vector space $M/IM$. Since $\mathbf{B}$ was arbitrarily chosen, any basis of $M$ has cardinality $|\mathbf{B}|=|\mathbf{B}’| =\dim_{R/I}(M/IM)$.

I would also greatly appreciate some feedback on whether or not this is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The statements are true for commutative rings, but fail in general for noncommutative ones.

Let $R$ be the endomorphism ring of a nonfinitely generated vector space $V$ over a field $k$; no need to invoke the axiom of choice, because you can take a vector space with basis $\{e_0,e_1,\dots,e_n,\dotsc\}$.

Then, as left modules over $R$, we have $R\cong R\oplus R$. So no, in general the cardinality of a basis in a free module is not an invariant.

Note that $R$ is a simple ring (it has no nontrivial maximal two-sided ideals) when $V$ has a countable basis, so one cannot in general reduce to ve

It is a standard exercise to show that the cardinality of a basis is indeed invariant for nonfinitely generated free modules (requires some form of choice, though).

A theorem by Leavitt states that, given any positive integer $k$, there exists a (noncommutative) ring $R$ such that $R^m\cong R^n$ as left modules if and only if $m\equiv n\pmod{k}$. The example above works for $k=1$.

Rings for which (left) finitely generated free modules invariant cardinality of bases are often called IBN (invariant basis number). Among IBN rings one finds the commutative rings and also the division rings. For the latter case, the standard proof for vector spaces over field carries over. For commutative rings one reduces to $k=R/I$, where $I$ is any maximal ideal.

Note that, in the initial example, $R$ is a simple ring (it has no nontrivial maximal two-sided ideals) when $V$ has a countable basis, so one cannot in general reduce to vector spaces like it can be done for commutative rings and this is exactly the obstruction for IBN.

---

W. G. Leavitt (1957), *Modules without invariant basis number*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 8, pp. 322-328

Comment: Interesting, I didn’t know that the result failed for non-commutative rings.

Comment: @egreg I have edited the question.Sorry for the inconvenience.I always assume that ring means commutative rings.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar Well, the answer also works for them.

Comment: @egreg Yes,indeed.

Comment: Just a historical comment. Although Corner did use rings $R$ with the properties you describe to show that there are abelian groups $A$ with $A\cong A\oplus A\oplus A$ but $A\not\cong A\oplus A$, the rings themselves were described earlier by  W.G.Leavitt (1957), *Modules without invariant basis number*,  Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **8**, pp. 322-328.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks, I'll fix the reference.

Answer (score 2):

1 is in fact true (edited: **when $R$ is commutative**). Indeed, a basis of $M$ over $R$ becomes a $k$-basis of $M \otimes_{R}k$, where $k$ is any residue field of $R$ (eg the quotient of $R$ by a maximal ideal). So any $R$-basis of $M$ has cardinality $\dim_k (M \otimes_{R} k)$.

Comment: Please prove what you are saying.

Comment: Can I prove $1.$ without introducing tensor product?

Comment: Take $k=R/\mathfrak{m}$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal, then the tensor product is just the quotient by $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: This is generally false for noncommutative rings.

Comment: I never thought for a second that $R$ could be non-commutative.

Comment: @Aphelli Different approach to rings: I never assume rings to be commutative. 